# Making a collection of UILabels from multiple UIButtons - IOS, Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, collections, uilabel, textfield

Trying to create multiple buttons and multiple labels, so that when you click a button an alert controller pops up (with textfield, OK button, clear button, and cancel button).

Im trying to minimize the amount of code, so I made a collection of labels:

```
@IBOutlet var textFieldLabel: [UILabel]!

@IBAction func textFieldTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Other11 Button Tapped")
    openOther11Alert()
}

func openOther11Alert() {
    //Create Alert Controller
    let alert = UIAlertController (title: "Other:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //Create Clear Action
    let bt = UIAlertAction(title: "CLEAR", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive){
        (action) in self.textFieldLabel[0].text = ""}
    alert.addAction(bt)

    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cancel)

    //Create OK Action
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {   (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
    let textfield = alert.textFields?[0]
    print(textfield?.text! as Any)
    self.textFieldLabel[0].text = textfield?.text!
    }
    alert.addAction(ok)

    //Add Text Field
    alert.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
    textfield.text = self.textFieldLabel[0].text
    textfield.placeholder = "Other"
    }

    //Present Alert Controller
    self.present(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

EDIT: 
I want the button clicked to correspond to the label. Currently, I am only referencing the the first element(label) in the array of labels with:

```
self.textFieldLabel[0].text
```

Instead of referencing "[0]" (the first label), I want to reference the button that was tapped, such that the button corresponds to the label.

Any idea if I can even do what I'm attempting?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `textFieldLabel` is an array of `UILabel`, not a single `UILabel`.

Comment: how would I reference an element of the array, in reference to a button?

Comment: Add tags to labels and buttons(in case of multiple buttons) compare the tag of button and correspond to that respective tagged label, make sense

Answer (score -1):

[UIAlertController Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller)

According to the documentation, the text fields attribute should give you an array of UITextFields. According to your error message, you are somehow getting a UILabel array. Perhaps the error message is talking about something else?